# Is there any created sub site use a same template code for me to reference?

Tags: open-source, framework, web

I am looking for a website framework, its mainly function is

such as it has a base domain `demo.com`, and I can create many sub site from it in the website.

`a.demo.com`, `b.demo.com`, `c.demo.com` and so on. 
and all the sub site use a same template, but them content are different.

is there any related framework or open source code I can use for reference?